# javascript functions to show and hide divs

Tags: javascript, function, html

Hello I have the following 2 JavaScript functions to open up a div and to close it.

```
<script>
    function show() {
        if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='none') {
          document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='block';
        }
    }
</script>



<script>
    function close() {
        if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='block') {
          document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='none';
        }
    }  
</script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="opener"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=show()>click here</a></div>
<div id="benefits" style="display:none;">
   some input in here plus the close button
   <div id="upbutton"><a onclick=close()></a></div>
</div>
```

For some reason the show function works how it should, but the close button does not do its job. So if there is someone who could help me out I really would appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery for these operations?

Comment: no, i never worked with jQuery before.

Comment: You're missing quotes around the function call <a onclick="close();">

Comment: There should be quotation marks around the functions: `onclick="close()"` Also, there is no content in the anchor associated with the `onclick`...

Comment: thanks for answering. setting quotation marks does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<script> 
    function show() { 
        if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hide() { 
        if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }   
</script> 


 <div id="opener"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick="return show();">click here</a></div> 
    <div id="benefits" style="display:none;">some input in here plus the close button 
           <div id="upbutton"><a onclick="return hide();">click here</a></div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: this works. two problems still left. the first one is that the anchor doesnt work anymore. by clicking the href it should set the anchor to the top of the site. and the second one still i a little bit complicated. by calling the hide() function there should being automatically focused an input field.

Comment: you can remove the "return false;" to add the anchor, but I think, the code won't work anymore. the automatically focused can be achieved with :  `document.getElementById('inputfieldID').focus();`

Comment: okay, i did the following: i removed return from both functions, renamed hide() into clo() and set the focus(). that all works great. besten dank und grüße aus berlin

Comment: return false; statement works for me!! As a newbie I don't know the reason:(

Answer (score 5):

I usually do this with classes, that seems to force the browsers to reassess all the styling.

```
.hiddendiv {display:none;}
.visiblediv {display:block;}
```

then use;

```
<script>  
function show() {  
    document.getElementById('benefits').className='visiblediv';  
}  
function close() {  
    document.getElementById('benefits').className='hiddendiv';  
}    
</script>
```

Note the casing of "className" that trips me up a lot

Answer (score 4):

The beauty of jQuery would allow us to do the following:

```
$(function()
{
    var benefits = $('#benefits');

    // this is the show function
    $('a[name=1]').click(function()
    { 
        benefits.show();
    });

    // this is the hide function
    $('a', benefits).click(function()
    {
        benefits.hide();
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could have 1 button toggle the display, like this:

```
$(function()
{
    // this is the show and hide function, all in 1!
    $('a[name=1]').click(function()
    { 
        $('#benefits').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the link inside to be clickable, meaning it needs a href with some content, and also, close() is a built-in function of window, so you need to change the name of the function to avoid a conflict.

```
<div id="upbutton"><a href="#" onclick="close2()">click to close</a></div>
```

Also if you want a real "button" instead of a link, you should use `<input type="button"/>` or `<button/>`.

Comment: +1 because you're the only one to mention the button. I kept looking at the other code and thinking "what button is he talking about? I don't see any!" lol

Answer (score 2):

check this:

click here

```
<div id="benefits" style="display:none;">some input in here plus the close button
       <div id="upbutton"><a onclick="close(); return false;"></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename the closing function as 'hide', for example and it will work.

```
function hide() {
    if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='block') {
      document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close appears to be a reserved word of some sort (Possibly referring to window.close). Changing it to something else appears to resolve the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/c7gdL/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the two with something like this [like jQuery does]:

```
function toggleMyDiv() {
 if (document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display=="block"){
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none"
  }
 else{
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
 }
}
```

..and use the same function in the two buttons - or generally in the page for both functions.